Hibernate / Jackson Serialization: Accessing Lazy Collection in Getter
I have a Spring / Hibernate REST API that is serializing the objects to JSON using Jackson.
Now, take my basic setup of a Company:
public class Company implements Serializable {
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    private List<Party> parties = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}

I have already installed the Hibernate 5 module in the spring configuration, so when 'parties' has not been initialised, it is not included in the JSON mapping - so far, I am happy:
mapperBuilder.modulesToInstall(
    new Hibernate5Module()
);

However, if I add a getter to my 'Company' object that uses 'parties', that method will throw an lazy load Exception within it, and therefore Spring will fail to write the JSON response
public class Company implements Serializable {
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    private List<Party> parties = new ArrayList<>();

    public Party getPrimaryAddress() {
        return this.parties == null ? null : this.parties.stream()
            .filter(party -> AddressType.PRIMARY_ADDRESS.equals(party.getAddressType()))
            .findAny()
            .orElse(null);
    }
}

I do not want to add a 'Hibernate.isInitialized' call within the getter, as it affects my service layer when still inside the JPA transaction.
Is there a way to ignore/handle lazy exceptions from within getters/accessors?

If you don't need the primaryAddress in your response add an @JsonIgnore annotation to the getPrimaryAddress() method. If you do, either make the parties EAGER instead of LAZY or write a dedicated query to make it EAGER for this case.

I need it, and wanted to avoid the dedicated query or eager fetching, as the same data is accessed from a place where it should be fetched, and a place where it shouldn't. I'm hoping for something more flexible
